# Не выводит список товаров по поиску. SQLite

Tags: swift, sqlite

На Firefox есть расширение Менеджер SQLite. В этом расширении делаю запрос 1 в 1 как я делаю в программе, но к сожалению в программе показывает что список пуст. А в расширении показывает весь список. Вот мой запрос

```
SELECT * FROM goods WHERE lower(name) LIKE '%прочий%' OR lower(descr) LIKE '%прочий%' ORDER BY (lower(name) LIKE '%прочий%') DESC  LIMIT 0, 20
```

вот ответ из расширения. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот код с программы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

на заметку, если делаю запрос с таким текстом - "про", то список приходит с базы все нормально.

вот код

```
// получение товаров из поиска
func getGoodsItemForSearch(offSet: Int, searchBarText: String)-> [GoodsItem] {
    openBase()
    // offSet для постраничной загрузки. 
    // searchBarText введенный текст в поиске.
    var where1 = ""
    let search1 = searchBarText.replacingOccurrences(of: "'", with: "\'\'", options: .literal, range: nil)

    if !searchBarText.isEmpty {
        let search = search1.lowercased()
        where1 += "WHERE lower(name) LIKE '%\(search)%' OR lower(descr) LIKE '%\(search)%' ORDER BY (lower(name) LIKE '%\(search)%') DESC"
    }

    let count = getCountInTable(table: "goods");

    let needCount = offSet * API.GET_MAX_SIZE_FROM_PAGE
    let startCount = offSet == 1 ? 0 : (needCount - API.GET_MAX_SIZE_FROM_PAGE) //API.GET_MAX_SIZE_FROM_PAGE = 20
    var limit = " LIMIT "
    if count < needCount {
        limit += String(startCount) + ", " + String(count-startCount)
    } else {
        limit += (String(startCount) + ", " + "\(API.GET_MAX_SIZE_FROM_PAGE)")
    }

    let resultSet : FMResultSet! = database!.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM goods \(where1) \(limit)", withArgumentsIn: nil)
    print("SELECT * FROM goods \(where1) \(limit)")
    var items:[GoodsItem] = []

    while resultSet.next() {
        let item = GoodsItem()
        item.name = resultSet.string(forColumn: "name")
        item.parent_id = resultSet.string(forColumn: "parent_id")
        item.price = resultSet.double(forColumn: "price")
        item.price_format = resultSet.string(forColumn: "price_format")
        item.ammount = resultSet.string(forColumn: "ammount")
        item.descr = resultSet.string(forColumn: "descr")
        item.id_serv = resultSet.string(forColumn: "id_serv") // recipe
        item.recipe = resultSet.string(forColumn: "recipe")
        item.img = resultSet.string(forColumn: "img")
        item.measure = resultSet.string(forColumn: "measure")
        items.append(item)
    }
    closeBase()
    print("items count goods where name = \(searchBarText) = \(items.count)")
    return items
}
```

Comment: код можно не скриншотом

Comment: Конечно. Уже добавил. выше в описании.

Comment: в офисе у товарища, который кодит на Android такой же запрос,  у него результат показывает такой же как у меня в расширении.

Comment: можно еще print'ы выложить для уверенности

Comment: первый принт  SELECT * FROM goods WHERE lower(name) LIKE '%прочий%' OR lower(descr) LIKE '%прочий%' ORDER BY (lower(name) LIKE '%прочий%') DESC  LIMIT 0, 20 второй принт                              
items count goods where name = прочий = 0